# Upgrade from Unity3D 4.1.5 to 4.2 causes CS0433 build error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to upgrade from 4.1.5 to 4.2. When I do and then open a project created under 4.1.5 I get a "*Assets/Uniject/Interface/IResourceLoader.cs(8,17): error CS0433: The imported type `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' is defined multiple times*" build error. The file just contains an interface with one property being an XDocument. I've google'd about this quite a bit and don't see any explanation/solution of the problem.

The System.Xml.Linq.dll is referenced in each of the generated projects, but this solution was building prior to the upgrade without problems.

I have uninstalled everything, wiped my \users\*\appdata\roaming\unity and C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity clean and rebooted before doing a fresh install and still get the same build error. I've blown away my project then gotten a fresh copy from source control with no love. And I've uninstalled 4.2 re-installed 4.1.5 and my project builds fine on a clean copy (since the 4.2 upgraded unity files are incompatible with 4.1.5 files).

What has changed, and how do I fix this so I can use the latest version of Unity?

Thanks, Mike

Comment: A bit of a guess but perhaps 4.2 install is finding the dll version installed with unity. You could try removing your own reference to it. Also check your project settings at Edit > Project Settings > Player > Other Settings and try changing to/from any subset options.

Comment: I found the issue. Unity3D 4.1.5 didn't include the System.Xml.Linq.dll file and the original developer that added Ninject manually added it. I deleted the file and we now build properly on 4.2.

4.2 now includes the DLL, hence the problem with multiple definitions.

Comment: @MikeLockhart Make that an actual answer instead of a comment and accept it. That's allowed and encouraged.